# jersey RESTful & shiro & oAuth tutorial

Tags: oauth, jersey

i'm looking for an good jersey & shiro & oAuth tutorial to secure my resouces.
Any hint would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written a [Jersey + Shiro](https://xebia.com/blog/apache-shiro/) tutorial weeks ago. Shiro's team is actually working on an OAuth authentication integration. For [a complete integration](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-119), I guess you'll have to wait for version 1.2.

Comment: first of all. Thanks for your response. I will give it a try

Comment: the link for the tutorial is broken

Comment: @ihebiheb the blog hosting the article has been replaced since, the url has been fixed accordingly