# user management system for a website

Tags: java, security, authentication

I am currently writing a site that will require a login to use. I have never had to do this before and I am looking for advice on the best way to do it.

I am guessing there are already opensource logins that I can just impliment into my site, I just need advice on which one to use and advice on where to look about getting information on how to use them.

If anyone has any knowledge or advice on how to go about it I would greatly appreciate it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at Apache Shiro [1] : "Apache Shiro is a powerful and easy-to-use Java security framework that performs authentication, authorization, cryptography, and session management".

For Shiro with oAuth, see thread [2].

[1] http://shiro.apache.org/

[2] [jersey RESTful & shiro & oAuth tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832252/jersey-restful-shiro-oauth-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

IMO Easiest thing to do would be to use an OAuth implementation for Java. OAuth lets your users auto-login using credentials from Google, etc

Check this out at Google: http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/

Answer (score 1):

The servlet specification explains how standard authentication works, and each server (tomcat, jetty, etc.) provides various options to store the users and their credentials.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html for how to configure Tomcat.

Spring-security is often used as an alternative.